# Push multiple Eclipse project to GitHub with EGit plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I want to push all my Eclipse projects to GitHub.I have created multiple repositories in the Github. I am able to push first project into first repository in  GitHub.But when i try to push the second project to the second repository, the second repository is having both the first and the second projects.So please help me out with this.

I am getting something like this
**Repository 1** : Project 1,
**Repository 2** : Project 1 + Project 2

My requirement
**Repository 1** : Project 1
**Repository 2** : Project 2

I am committing and pushing project 1 and project 2 separately.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure project1 and project2 are in their own local git repo, not in their own folder of the same git repo.

If you do have two local repo, then double-check the remotes associated with project in your [Eclipse git Repositories view](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories)

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e2/RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png]

You need *different* remote repo

For that, create a new remote node as needed:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/6/66/RepoMgrNewRemote.png]